# Real time tracking of android device on server request

Tags: android, mobile, gps, real-time

I'm looking to implement, real time location tracking for android apps.

The server would request a specific device's real time location which needs to be shown on google map. can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: get location of particular mobile device and send data to server, and other side take data from server and display on your admin app. do u want to show that person location on map in **Android Application** only ?

Comment: I want to fetch the location only on server request. So the server will request the location and show on google maps on admin panel

Answer (score 1):

use geo coding google api to do this stuff.... through gps in android write a android app, that should send latitude and longitude position for every 10 or 20sec so that you can make a variable for latitude and longitude so that new value get updated and stored